# Definition of graph, using half-edges.

Tags: graph-theory, definition

There are several valid definitions of a (multi)graph. Let me quote the one I use (ref.1 §1.1):

**Definition:** A graph is a triple $(V,E,\psi)$ where $V$ is the vertex set, $E$ the edge set, and $\psi\colon E\to V^2$ a relation that associates with each edge an unordered pair consisting of two vertices (not necessarily distinct).

An alternative definition is that a graph is a set of half-edges (e.g., ref.2, §5.1):

**Definition:** A graph is a set of half-edges along with a set $V$ of disjoint subsets of half edges known as vertices which partition the set of half edges, and a set $E$ of disjoint pairs of half edges known as internal edges.

How is this latter definition understood in the context of the former? What is the precise definition of a half-edge, when we regard a graph as a triple $(V,E,\psi)$?

**References.**

1. Bondy, Murty - Graph Theory with Applications.
2. Yeats - A Combinatorial Perspective on Quantum Field Theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from the triple $(V,E,\psi)$, or from basically any other definition of graphs, we have a half-edge $h_{v,e}$ for every pair $(v,e) \in V \times E$ such that $v$ is incident to $e$. (In the formal definition with $\psi$, a pair $(v,e)$ such that $v \in \psi(e)$.)

If $e$ is a loop, we should probably be more careful and have two half-edges $h_{v,e}^1$ and $h_{v,e}^2$, because we still want the edge to correspond to a pair of half-edges.

Then a vertex $v$ in the original definition corresponds to the set of half-edges with vertex $v$, and an edge $e$ in the original definition corresponds to the set of (exactly two) half-edges with edge $e$.

Comment: Thanks, quite convincing. I'll think about it, and accept the answer later on.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I still have a question: is a labelled graph in the standard sense in a one-to-one correspondence with a labelled graph in the half-edge sense? In other words, is there a unique graph in the second setting for each graph in the first setting? Intuitively, I believe that the answer is *yes*, but could you please confirm it for me? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. By "labelled graph" I just mean "graph" (as in the definitions above). To rephrase my question: if we want to count graphs, is it equivalent to do so in either setting? or are there "more graphs" if we work with one definition instead of the other. Say, trees with three vertices; are there as many of them if we regard them as in the standard definition and in the half-edge definition? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sure. I mean on a fixed vertex and edge set (and a fixed half-edge set for the second case). Take the $3$-star $K_{1,3}$. There are $3\times 4$ different graphs with vertices $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and edges $\{a,b,c\}$. Are there $24$ graphs over the half-edge set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$?

Comment: Nope, there are $\binom{6}{3} \cdot 2^3 = 160$ different ways to make a $K_{1,3}$ with a fixed half-edge set. But I don't think this is a particularly interesting thing to count (and it's not what we count when we count labeled trees, where the edge set is left "anonymous").

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for your patience. There are still some things that are bugging me but they are beyond the scope of this post. Cheers!