# Definition of half edge

Tags: graph-theory

In this post [Definition of graph, using half-edges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678435/definition-of-graph-using-half-edges)  a graph is defined in terms of half edges. I googled to find the definition of half edges but i did not find it. 
My question is what is the definition of half edge?

Comment: It is explained in the answer to the link you gave.